# /dev/ttyUSB0: End of file

Tags: 16.04, drivers, serial-port

I've started working on ubuntu 16.04 and every now and then I run into this issue: I'm using a serial port without problem, plugging and unplugging etc, and at some point I start getting the error:

```
/dev/ttyUSB0: End of file
```

I can't get that to go away by unplugging. Reboot solves this. I suspect this is a driver issue...
Any better solutions?

Note: This is not a permissions issue, I have my user setup to access serial, and I tried sudo just in case.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently there some issue with the serial drivers. Haven't figured out exactly what the problem is, but the following gets things running again:

```
# remove drivers
sudo modprobe -r ftdi_sio
sudo modprobe -r usbserial
# get driver back up
sudo modprobe ftdi_sio
```